# Prove sum of 2 little 'o is equal to the little 'o from the sum

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

I need to prove if

for $f(x) = o(h(x))$ and $g(x) = o(q(x))$

then $f(x) + g(x) = o(|h(x)| + |q(x)|)$

I think that this is false but I am struggling to find a counter example.

Comment: It's the little o notation right?

Comment: If you can't find a counterexample, it's a good idea to spend a little time trying to prove it. If you don't manage to prove it, the way you fail often helps finding counterexamples.

Comment: yes it's the little o. I have tried proving it pretty much the exact way in the below hint but I'm uncertain if you can assume that both of the coefficients are the same i.e. a, I take two different coefficients and using the triangle inequality I'm unsure if you can pull the constants out.

Comment: Also that example is without mods.

Comment: Apologies, it does answer the question

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $|f(x)| \le a |h(x)|$ and $|g(x)| \le a |q(x)|$ then 
$|f(x) + g(x)| \le a (|h(x)| + |q(x)|)$.

Comment: The above suggested post provides a counter example so your case appears to be the definition for big O

Comment: Not at all.   This is about $o$.  The "counter example" was to a different question, without absolute values.